# how to put add code that when the text(textview) is clicked, an image will appear(function like an alert dialog) .?

Tags: android

Questions.java

```
    public void onClick(View v) {  

            if (q1.isChecked()) {
                int count = 0;
                for (CheckBox cb : cbList) {
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }           
                if (count <= 1) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.negative).show(); 
                } else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(R.string.positive).show(); 
                }
            }

        }
```

question.xml

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/q1a"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sas1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sas1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

note: never mind the checkbox

how to put add code that when the text(textview) is clicked, an image will appear( like an alert dialog) something like that.?

Comment: Try to add an image with default setting invisible and change it state to visible if textView was clicked

Comment: duplicates here http://stackoverflow.com/q/22199054/2001247, http://stackoverflow.com/q/22200527/2001247, http://stackoverflow.com/q/22211776/2001247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a custom AlertDialog

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_own_custom_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("The Title...");

    // set the custom dialog components
    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_own_image_resource);

    ...
```

Comment: but i already have an onlick for my button..how can i do that code.? @jmhostalet