# image will appear when text is clicked using alert dialog

Tags: android

```
sas12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "                                                                    ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        LinearLayout toastView = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
        ImageView imageCodeProject = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        toastView.addView(imageCodeProject, 0);
        toast.show();               
    }
});
```

This is my code..that when a text(textview) is clicked..a toast with image will appear "imageCodeProject.setImageResource(R.drawable.image)"..then i want it to execute by using an Alert dialog so that the image will not disappear in 5seconds and i want it to disappear when i want it to disappear..

here is an example of what i want to happen..

Fevertxt = fever image

"Fevertxt" is the textview and "fever image" is an image that will show what a fever looks like..

Comment: your question i not clear can you explain `i want it to execute by using an Alert dialog so that the image will not disappear in 5seconds and i want it to disappear when i want it to disappear..` lines to get more help from us

Comment: i want that the image will disappear manually..  @ρяσѕρєя

Comment: i want that the image will disappear manually.. @K

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to put add code that when the text(textview) is clicked, an image will appear(function like an alert dialog) .?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009511/how-to-put-add-code-that-when-the-texttextview-is-clicked-an-image-will-appea)